# Operators in Javascript

Tags: javascript, operators

Can someone explain this to me? It's about operators in javascript.

I've seen a sample code like c += a + (+b)

Is this the correct equivalent? c = c + a + (+b) ?

I can understand the rest except that +b, why does it have a `+` in `b`?

Comment: See *unary plus* here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators

Comment: And to answer the part of the question that isn't addressed in the duplicate, yes, `c += …` is equivalent to `c = c + …`.